# Can't get anything to update the html on page

Tags: c#, webforms

I've been trying to get the html of my site to update from the code behind, I have almost no experience in winforms at all so chances are I'm missing something obvious but nothing seems to work at all.

I have a div:

```
<div id="statusContainer" class="status-container" runat="server"></div>
```

And I'm trying to dynamically have the contents populate on page load, I've tried changing `InnerHTML`, inserting a list view and binding a list to it, adding a literal control inside that and using .text, and building a `HtmlGenericControl` in the backend and adding it to `statusContainer.Controls.Add()`.

What I've tried in code form:

```
statusContainer.InnerHTML += "<p>Test</p>"
```

InnerHTML property contained my text, but page was empty.

```
 <div class="status-container">
       <asp:Literal ID="statusBoxes" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 </div>
```

then in the code behind:

```
statusBoxes.Text += "<p>Test</p>"
```

I've deleted my listview code but it was just a basic asp listview with 3 properties in itemtemplate, and a placeholder in layouttemplate. Then in my code behind i did.

```
statusBoxes.DataSource = statuses;
statusBoxes.DataBind();
```

All of these look like they work in the backend, if I inspect the variable it will reflect that my content has been added to the inner html, or that the list view has been bound properly, or that the literal contains my text, but nothing shows on the page, the div is just permanently empty.

Comment: These all sound like approaches that would work.  If you include your actual .aspx and .aspx.cs code for one of the things you have tried it will help.  This is because where the code is placed in the code behind can be important.

Comment: If you use view page source in the browser is the div there?

Comment: @DaveBarnett Turns out it was because of page postbacks, i was working in someone elses codebase and their front end and back end have basically become one in the same thing, step 1 is pulling it apart because right now there's 0 seperation of concerns

Comment: I feel your pain.